# Magento: why using EAV instead of MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, magento, entity-attribute-value

I am learning magento, and I just read about the EAV. If I understood it correctly it is like a simulation of noSQL database over an SQL database.
So this way, for example, a product like a pencil can have different attributes in its description than a computer, or a ball.

But I read about this system in a book things like:

> All this  exibility and power is not free, and there is a price to pay; implementing the EAV model results in having our entity data distributed on a large number of tables, for example, just the Product Model is distributed on around 40 different tables.
>
> [...]
>
> Another major downside of EAV is the loss of performance when retrieving large collections of EAV objects and an increase on the database query complexity. Since the data is more fragmented (stored in more tables), selecting a single record involves several joins.

I'm completely new, so maybe I'm loosing something, but my question is:

**Why use this complicated way instead of using a document based database as mongoDB?**

Comment: EAV is not like noSQL, and it is especially not a simulation. It's using a relational database the way they were meant to be used, but at an advanced level. I agree that a document database might be a good replacement, but they are not equivalent.

Comment: You are right, it is not a simulation. Maybe I did not explained it very well, I know that EAV is pure SQL, but I think the way it is used is trying to 'emulate' a NoSQL database despite it is used the way they meant to be used as SQL.

Comment: I don't even think it is doing that. Both EAV and NoSql are trying to solve the same problem, but it doesn't mean that EAV is trying to be NoSQL. It's like saying that refrigeration and pickling are ways of extending the life of food, but you can't say that refrigeration is emulating pickling.

Comment: Well when I said 'emulate' I was trying to say (as you said ;-) ) that they are trying to solve the same problem. That's why I wrote emulate with simple quotation marks. I understand that  they are quite different. But I don't understand why use one instead of the other that seems to have more advantages in this kind of use. Perhaps there is a reason to use EAV instead of a NoSQL like mongodb, but just now I don't see that reason. I'm just trying to understand that.